# How can we pass from $\dot z=Az+\varepsilon g(z,\dot z,t)$ to $\dot x=\varepsilon g(x,\dot x,t)$?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_averaging#Non-autonomous_class_of_systems:_more_examples), I want to write $$\begin{pmatrix}\dot z_1\\\dot z_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}z_1\\z_2\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0\\ \varepsilon g(z,\dot z,t)\end{pmatrix},$$

in the form of $$\begin{pmatrix}\dot x_1\\\dot x_2\end{pmatrix}=\varepsilon e^{-tA}\begin{pmatrix}0\\g(x,\dot x,t)\end{pmatrix},$$
where $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$.

---

The strategy is to solve the homogeneous system (i.e. $\varepsilon =0$), i.e. $$\begin{pmatrix}\dot z_1\\\dot z_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}z_1\\z_2\end{pmatrix},$$
what gives $\Phi(t)=e^{tA}$ as fundamental solution. After they say : Then the time-dependent change of coordinates is $z(t)=\Phi(t)x$ where $x$ is the coordinates respective to the standard form.

**Q1)** what mean : $x$ is the coordinate respective to the standard from ?

After they say "we derivate in both side which gives $$\begin{pmatrix}\dot x_1\\\dot x_2\end{pmatrix}=\varepsilon e^{-tA}\begin{pmatrix}0\\g(x,\dot x,t)\end{pmatrix},$$

**Q2)** When I derivate both side, I get $$z'(t)=\Phi'(t)x(t)+x'(t)\Phi(t)=Ae^{tA}x(t)+x'(t)e^{tA}\implies x'(t)=e^{-tA}z(t)-Ax(t).$$

How can I get the wished form ?

Comment: You should take the header "This article has multiple issues. ... improve it" heavily into account. The two functions $g$ are not the same, the last one should better be a $\tilde g(x,\dot x,t)=g(e^{At}x,Ae^{At}x+e^{At}\dot{x},t)$ as derived in the answer.

Comment: @LutzL: What do you mean by "You should take the header "This article has multiple issues. ... improve it" heavily into account" ?Unfortunately, in my problem, I would prefer very much that the same $g$ works... to bad...

Comment: I mean the wikipedia article, right on top. And no, if you change the variables then you also change the equations governing them. You have to do that correctly to get useful results.

Answer (score 1):

Define
$$ \binom{z_1}{z_2}=e^{At}\binom{x_1}{x_2}$$
and put it in the orignal equation to get
$$ Ae^{At}\binom{x_1}{x_2}+e^{At}\binom{\dot{x}_1}{\dot{x}_2}=Ae^{At}\binom{x_1}{x_2}+\binom{0}{\epsilon g(e^{At}x,Ae^{At}x+e^{At}\dot{x},t)}. $$
From this, it is easy to see
$$ \binom{\dot{x}_1}{\dot{x}_2}=\epsilon e^{-At}\binom{0}{g(e^{At}x,Ae^{At}x+e^{At}\dot{x},t)}.$$

Comment: why do you have the equality in the second formula ? You suppose that $(x_1,x_2)$ solve originl system ? Moreover, at the end, wikipedia get $g(x,\dot x,t)$ and it's not what you have.

Comment: I don't get the point. $(z_1,z_2)$ solve the homogeneous equation... not the original problem..

Comment: suppose $\binom{z_1}{z_2}$ solves the original problem.